# Redshift - Select Max Date and 2nd Max Date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have an `uploaddate` column in my database and I would simply like to pull every record that has the most recent date (will be 1000's of records with the same `uploaddate`).

Similarly I would also like to do the exact same select but instead of the latest max date, it would take the previous `uploaddate`.

As an example:

```
row1 data1 2018-07-23 09:35:00
row2 data2 2018-07-23 09:35:00
row3 data3 2018-07-23 09:20:00
row4 data4 2018-07-23 09:20:00
row5 data5 2018-07-23 09:10:00
row6 data6 2018-07-23 09:01:00
```

The first query would select

```
row1 data1 2018-07-23 09:35:00
row2 data2 2018-07-23 09:35:00
```

and the second query would select

```
row3 data3 2018-07-23 09:20:00
row4 data4 2018-07-23 09:20:00
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by uploaddate desc) as seqnum
      from schema1.table1 t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;  -- or 2 for the second maximum
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this is a really dumb question but what do I replace `t` with if my table is named `schema1.table1`. I haven't seen the t.* notation before. Having some trouble executing this :/ I